# map, then iterate - why?

Tags: python, for-loop, coding-style, iteration

In [DEAP example](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/default/examples/ga_onemax.html) (Python framework) there is a code:

```
# Evaluate the entire population
fitnesses = list(map(toolbox.evaluate, pop))
for ind, fit in zip(pop, fitnesses):
    ind.fitness.values = fit
```

why they use `map`, then `for`? Why not just:

```
for ind in pop:
    ind.fitness.values = toolbox.evaluate(ind)
```

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that it might be important to evaluate all calls to `toolbox.evaluate()` before the assigning to any of the `ind.fitness.values` must happen.  Maybe a concurrency issue?  Or assigning has side-effects?

Comment: Probably just the remains of hacking the code.  Maybe in an older version there was something between to two lines using `fitnesses` for a different purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the DEAP developer.

We use the map so that we can easily parallelize the evaluation by replacing the map by a parallel map.

Later in the examples, we use a toolbox with a map registered in it (`__buitins__.map`) that can be replaced by `multiprocessing.Pool.map` or `scoop.futures.map`. You can look at the documentation for how to distribute the evaluation [here](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part4.html)

Comment: sorry to say this, the link doesn't work. Could you update the link? thank you for your help.

Comment: @ZongzeWu Done!